# I am able to run an 8x10 but not 9x11 matrix

Tags: matrices

I am able to run an 8 x 10 matrix but not 9 x 11 matrix

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
 
This runs

    $\begin{matrix}
        x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
        & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
        &  & x_3 & c_x & x_5 &  &  &  &  &  \\
        &  &  & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &  &  &  &  \\
        &  &  &  & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &  &  &  \\
        &  &  &  &  & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 &  &  \\
        &  &  &  &  &  & x_7 & x_8 & x_9 &  \\
        &  &  &  &  &  &  & x_8 & x_9 & x_10 
    \end{matrix} $

But this does not run
$ \begin{matrix}
    x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\
    & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 &  &  &  &  &   &  & \\
    &  & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 &  &  &  &   &  & \\
    &  &  & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &  &  &   &  & \\
    &  &  &  & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &  &   &  & \\
    &  &  &  &  & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 &   &  & \\
    &  &  &  &  &  & x_7 & x_8 & x_9  &  & \\
    &  &  &  &  &  &  & x_8 & x_9 & x_10 & \\
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & x_9 & x_10 & x_1 
\end{matrix} $



\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}`

Comment: Where should I place this `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}`? Preamble or where, please?

Comment: preamble or technically anywhere before the matrix

Comment: it doesn't have to be 20 of course it is an arbitrary maximum set to 10 initially

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}`